# Dynamic Programming Matrix Calculation Issue

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, optimization, dynamic-programming

Selling rods business where each rod's price depends on its length. Given a price table `T`, where `T[i]` is the price ($) of a rod of length `i`, the task is to cut a rod of length `l` into pieces to maximize the total selling price.

Given `T = [1, 6, 11, 15, 19, 21]` for rod lengths 1 through 6, and `l = 12`, the objective is to determine the optimal cutting strategy to maximize profit.

The dynamic approach is to define `PM` (Maximum Price) and `NB` (Number of Cuts) matrices where `PM[i][j]` calculates the max price for a rod of length `j` using pieces up to length `i`, and `NB[i][j]` records the number of pieces of length `i` used.

#### Initialization:

`for all 1 ≤ i ≤ n, PM[i][0] = NB[i][0] = 0.`

#### Recursive Scheme:

For every integer `1 ≤ i ≤ n` and `1 ≤ j ≤ l`:

[image: Dynamic Programming Formula]

Here, `NB[i][j]` is the index `k` that provides the maximum value in the formula above.

`PM[n][l]` represents the maximum total price achievable, and `NB[n][l]` counts the number of pieces of size `n` required to reach this price.

I'm encountering issues with the recursive step. For entry `[6,12]` in a `[6x12]` matrix, I'm considering `k` values in the set {0,1,2} since `k` is bounded by `12/6`. My interpretation is to select the maximum from these `k` values. However, this approach feels like it may be unnecessarily limiting my options for `k`.

Here's how I understand the components of the `PM` formula:

- `[i-j]` points to the entry directly above.
- `[j-k*i]` moves left in the current row, decreasing as `k` increases.
- `k*T[i]` computes the total price for `k` pieces of length `i`.

I'm looking for clarification on properly understand the recursive formula and utilizing `k`. Any insights would be appreciated

code

```
T = [0, 1, 6, 11, 15, 19, 21] 
l = 12  
PM = [[0 for _ in range(l + 1)] for _ in range(len(T))]
NB = [[0 for _ in range(l + 1)] for _ in range(len(T))]

for i in range(1, len(T)):
    for j in range(1, l + 1):
        max_profit = 0
        max_k = 0
        for k in range(j // i + 1):
            profit = PM[i - 1][j - k * i] + k * T[i]
            if profit > max_profit:
                max_profit = profit
                max_k = k
        PM[i][j] = max_profit
        NB[i][j] = max_k

for row in PM:
    print(row)
for row in NB:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Why do you think `j // i + 1` is the same as `floor(j / i)`?

Comment: they are equivalent. If changed, the output matrix is the same. Im trying to understand the PM formula correctly as stated.

Comment: I gave a non-DP answer, but should have asked -- is a non-DP efficient answer helpful or do you need a DP solution?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Im trying to understand the DP approach :)

Comment: What do you mean by "encountering issues" and "unnecessarily limiting my options for `k`?" The formula you shared makes sense. But your question is unclear. What do you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in Ruby, which is close to Python and very close to the OP's solution. For those who don't know Ruby treat it as pseudo-code. With my comments you should be able to understand what I have done.

We are give the values of each length cut:

```
T = [1, 6, 11, 15, 19, 21]
```

The value of length `i` equals `T[i-1]`.

Now suppose the length of rod to chop up is

```
len = 12
```

We begin by defining an array of `len+1` hashes (dictionaries in Pydc:

```
best = Array.new(len+1) { { tot: 0, first: nil } }
  #=> [{:tot=>0, :first=>nil}, {:tot=>0, :first=>nil}, ...{:tot=>0, :first=>nil}]
```

For each `i = 1,..., len`, `best[i]` will be altered to provide the maximum return if the rod is of length `i`. In addition, it will provide information needed to reconstruct the optimal solution.

The calculations are as follows.

```
(1..len).each do |n|
  # loop over rod lengths n = 1,..., N
  (1..[n, T.size].min).each do |i|
  # loop over the size of the first cut to be made
     # compute cand, the optimal value of cutting a rod of length n if
     # the first cut is length i
     cand = T[i-1] + best[n-i][:tot]
     # update best[n] if the value of the last cut being i is greater 
     # than the previously best-known value
     if cand > best[n][:tot]
       # save the new best value and the associated first cut length
       best[n] = { tot: cand, first: i }
     end
  end
end
```

```
best
  #=> [
  # {:tot=>0,  :first=>nil},  0* (5-5)
  # {:tot=>1,  :first=>1},    1
  # {:tot=>6,  :first=>2},    2
  # {:tot=>11, :first=>3},    3
  # {:tot=>15, :first=>4},    4
  # {:tot=>19, :first=>5},    5* (9-4)  T[5] => 19
  # {:tot=>22, :first=>3},    6
  # {:tot=>26, :first=>3},    7
  # {:tot=>30, :first=>3},    8
  # {:tot=>34, :first=>4},    9* (12-3) T[4] => 15
  # {:tot=>38, :first=>5},   10
  # {:tot=>41, :first=>3},   11
  # {:tot=>45, :first=>3}    12*        T[3] => 11
  # ]
```

Upon examining `best[12]` we see that the optimal value for a rod of length `12` is `45` and the associated first cut is of length of `3`. The value of that first cut is `T[3] #=> 11`.

After removing the first cut we consider how a rod of length `12 - 3 #=> 9` would be cut optimally. We see above that the optimal value would be `34` and length of the first cut (of the smaller rod) is `4`, earning `T[4] #=> 15`.

That leaves a rod of `9 - 4 #=> 5`. The optimal value of cutting a rod of length `5` is seen to be `19` and the first cut is `5` (i.e., no residual rod)

`5 - 5 #=> 0`, telling us we are finished. The optimal solution is found to employ one each of rods of length `3`, `4` and `5`.

---

We now move this to a method and include the recovery of the optimal number of each length cut.

```
def chop_it(len)
  best = Array.new(len+1) { { tot: 0, first: nil } }
  (1..len).each do |n|
    (1..[n, T.size].min).each do |i|
      cand = T[i-1] + best[n-i][:tot]
      if cand > best[n][:tot]
        best[n] = { tot: cand, first: i }
      end
    end
  end
  recover(best)
end
```

```
def recover(best)
  cuts = {}
  n = best.size - 1
  while n > 0
    m = best[n][:first]
    if cuts.has_key?(m)
      cuts[m] += 1
    else          
      cuts[m] = 1
    end
    n -= m
  end
  cuts
end
```

```
chop_it(12)
  #=> {3=>1, 4=>1, 5=>1}
```

As before, if the rod is of length `12`, we should cut one piece each of lengths `3`, `4` and `5`.

```
chop_it(467)
  #=> {3=>1, 4=>1, 5=>92}
```

If the rod is of length `467`, we cut one piece each of lengths `3` and `4`, and `92` pieces of length `5`.

Comment: The number of pieces is an input and may not be optimal.

Comment: Oops! One of us misread the question, and it was me. I apologize.

Comment: Not a problem, @Dave.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Great approach. Im trying to understand if there is a way to find all the best possible solutions from the second matrix (NB). For example for chop(12), there is also 3 pieces * (T[4] =14) = 45

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I'll look to expanding my answer to cover that. I believe you meant `T[4] = 15`.

Answer (score 0):

O(1) Non-DP approach: all lengths are (total length) / (num pieces), except for (total length) % (num pieces), which are 1 more. This simple approach is possible for your pricing table because the benefit of incrementing length by 1 is nonincreasing by length. For pricing tables where this doesn't hold, an alternate approach would be needed.

```
1 -> 2: +5 value
2 -> 3: +5 value
3 -> 4: +4 value
4 -> 5: +4 value
5 -> 6: +2 value
```

This suggests that the optimal solution will be to have all lengths as close to average as possible.

Given 12 pieces of length 1-6, the length of the rod must be 12-72 or there is no solution.

All pieces should be either floor(length/12) or ceiling(length/12), with the count that take the ceiling being length%12.

**Example**

Say length = 50. Since 50 / 12 = 4 and 50 % 12 = 2, we have 10 pieces of length 4 and 2 of length 5. The value is 10 * 11 + 2 * 15 = 140.

Could we do better? Since the number of cuts is fixed, the only changes we can make involve moving units of length around.

```
modification   result (effect on value)
4->3 & 4->5       15->11 & 15->19; net 30->30; no effect
4->3 & 5->6       15->11 & 19->21; net 34->32; bad outcome
4->2 & 4->6       15-> 6 & 15->21; net 30->27; bad outcome
4->2, 4->5, 4->5  15->6, 15->19, 15->19; net 45->44; bad outcome
etc...
```